# Too short characters are not right padded in sql clause IN with H2 database

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table with a char column in H2.

```
create table mytable (col_fixed_width char(4));
insert into mytable (col_fixed_width) values ('01  ');
insert into mytable (col_fixed_width) values ('02  ');
```

When I use the equal symbol in a sql clause where or the sql clause IN with a unique value, I get a result. The right padding is done correctly by H2.

But when I use the sql clause IN with several values, the query returns nothing. The right padding doesn't work.

```
SELECT * from mytable where col_fixed_width='01'; -- OK
SELECT * from mytable where col_fixed_width IN ('01'); -- OK
SELECT * from mytable where col_fixed_width IN ('01', '02');  -- KO
SELECT * from mytable where col_fixed_width IN ('01') OR col_fixed_width IN ('02');  -- KO
SELECT * from mytable where col_fixed_width IN ('01  ', '02  '); -- OK
SELECT * from mytable where col_fixed_width IN ('01  ') OR col_fixed_width IN ('02  '); -- OK
```

Any help would be appreciate to understand the issue.

h2 v2.1.214

Comment: Does "KO" represent those not working? So queries 3 and 4 don't return anything?

Comment: @Isolated yes. Queries 3 and 4 don't return anything

Comment: As a rule of thumb I don't really trust any silent "right padding", not in H2, not in any other database. If the data type is `CHAR` I always make sure the length of the literal strings (typically parameters coming from the UI) match the column size, before even trying the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `CHARACTER` (`CHAR`) data type for variable-length strings. SQL has `CHARACTER VARYING` (`VARCHAR`) data type for this purpose.

Values of `CHARACTER` data type are right-padded with spaces to the declared length of data type and when you try to compare these values with character strings of another length it is a complex question whether they will be considered equal or not. According to the SQL Standard they may be equal just like they may be not equal, because equality of `01`   to `01` should depend only on characteristics of collation.

H2 doesn't support per column, per data type or per value collations, but H2 has historic dirty tricks for the `CHARACTER` data type and usually comparisons with this data type effectively use a collation with `PAD SPACE` characteristic, unlike comparison operations with other character strings, they use some collation with `NO PAD` characteristic by default.

Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work well with the `IN` predicate, this is a known not yet resolved bug:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3385

The simplest workaround is a proper selection of data types depending on your needs. If all possible values have exactly the same length you can use the `CHARACTER` data type with this length, in all other cases this archaic defective by design data type should be avoided, its padding with spaces is a source of various problems.

Comment: thanks @Evgenij Ryazanov for the explanation and the link to the bug. I agree with you about the use of varchar instead of char but unfortunately I'm working on a old database which has char data type.